# Combinatorics about codes

Tags: combinatorics

A certain code is composed by $6$ characters, from which $4$ are digits and $2$ are vowels.
How many different codes can you form, such that it must have one $3$, and also one "a". The vowels have to be together at the end of the code.

I obtained $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 5 \cdot 4$, but it isn't correct. What did I miss?

The correct answer is $(1 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 4 \cdot 1) \cdot 4 \cdot 2$; the $4$ outside the brackets is for rearraging digits; the $2$ is for rearraging vowels.

Thank you

Comment: you considered that the number 3 can only be chosen first when it can be chosen second thiord and fourth

Comment: I missed the "vowels at the end of the code" rule, so my answer was invalid.

Comment: yeah i noticed that @AlgorithmsX

Comment: "r" is not a vowel..... @Isham

Comment: well I meant 1234ea for example

Comment: @Isham ok, but can you make and answer for the post?

Comment: can have or must have ? big difference.

Comment: what do you mean distinct, i never said they have to be distinct, only when it comes to 3 and "a" @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: I was just thinking of where you could be going wrong. that's all, if all the vowels and such needed to be distinct then it changes the math quite a bit.

Comment: no they dont have to be distinct @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: whether order within each section changing actually changes the code could also change the math.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee the exact solution is 23328, can you figure out how im supposed to arrange the code ?

Comment: Providing a numerical answer in a comment as additional detail is an extremely inadequate way of making it clear that your real problem is that you don't understand what your textbook is asking you to do and that you have failed to write down a clear statement of what your question is. I am voting to close your question as unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider cases.

Neither $3$ nor $a$ is used:  The four positions reserved for digits can each be filled in $9$ ways.  The two positions reserved for vowels can each be filled in $4$ ways.  Hence, there are

> $9^4 \cdot 4^2$

permissible codes in this case.

The digit $3$ is used, but the vowel $a$ is not:  Choose in which of the four positions reserved for digits $3$ is used.  The remaining three positions reserved for digits can be filled in $9$ ways.  The two positions reserved for vowels can be filled in $4$ ways.  Hence, there are

> $$4 \cdot 9^3 \cdot 4^2$$

permissible codes in this case.

The vowel $a$ is used, but the digit $3$ is not:  The four positions reserved for digits can each be filled in $9$ ways.  Choose in which of the two positions reserved for vowels $a$ is used.  The remaining position can be filled with a vowel in $4$ ways.  Hence, there are

> $$9^4 \cdot 2 \cdot 4$$

permissible codes in this case.

Both $3$ and $a$ are used:  Choose in which of the four positions reserved for digits $3$ is used.  Each of the three remaining positions reserved for digits can be filled in $9$ ways.  Choose in which of the two positions reserved for vowels $a$ is used.  The remaining position can be filled with a vowel in $4$ ways.  Hence, there are

> $$4 \cdot 9^3 \cdot 2 \cdot 4$$

permissible codes in this case.

Since the four cases above are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the total number of permissible codes can be found by adding them.

Comment: Nice answer, but the solutions only consider correct the last thing you put, when both "a" and 3 are used. I believe the book that im using has some serious grammar isues...

Comment: The last case should be phrased "How many six-character codes with exactly one $3$ and one $a$ can be formed if the first four positions are digits and the last two positions are vowels?"

Comment: yeah, it should have been phrased like that...

Answer (score 3):

There are $9^4 + 4\times 9^3$ sequences of $4$ digits with at most one $3$ ($9^4$ with no $3$ and $9^3$ choices for each of the other $3$ digits if you put a $3$ in one of the $4$ positions). Similarly, there are $4^2 + 2\times4$ sequences of vowels with at most one $a$. So that gives $(9^4 + 4\times 9^3)(4^2 + 2\times4)$ ways of concatenating a sequence of the first type with a sequence of the second (which is what you have to do, because the vowels are required to follow the digits).

Comment: not correct because the question was phrased incorrectly.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is a rubbish comment. You asked a perfectly unambiguous question and have been given several correct answers to it. You can't say those answers are incorrect because they disagree with your failed attempt to state the problem precisely.

Comment: i meant that the question from where i took it has unclear phrasing

Comment: So fix your question on MSE so that it embraces the help you have already received and asks for clarification with what your textbook is asking for. It is really offensive to say an answer is not correct because you asked the wrong question. Think about it!

Comment: understood, sry about that

Comment: Thanks. I've retracted my close vote, but it would be nice if you could include a bit of the history in the question, so that the correct answers you got to the question as you originally stated make sense in context. And then maybe add your own answer to the question as you eventually understood it.

Answer (score 0):

Let the numebr of vowels be $v$ (can be 5 or 6, depending on whether we count y or not, or even more like û,ê,ú, ô etc. in Frisian e.g.). We'll agree on $10$ digits.

Then the number of codes in total (4 digits followed by 2 vowels) is $10^4 v^2$.

How many bad digit codes are there?, then we have $i$ digits $3$ where $i=2,3,4$.
For fixed $i$: this gives us $\binom{4}{i}$ ways to choose the places for the $3$'s, and $9^{4-i}$ choices for the remaining places, and $v^2$ for the vowels.

How many bad vowel codes? : it needs two $a's$ so we have no choice for vowels and so $10^4$ bad vowel codes.

How many codes are counted doubly: Bad digit and bad vowels: the same counting as above gives $\binom{4}{i} 9^{4-1}$ summed over $i=2,3,4$.

So in all I get $$10^4 \cdot v^2 - v^2(6 \cdot 9^2 + 4\cdot 9 +1) - 10^4 +  (6 \cdot 9^2 +4\cdot 9 +1)= 10^4(v^2-1) - 523(v^2-1) = (10^4 - 523)(v^2-1)$$

Comment: not correct for v=5

Comment: What's the difference then (how man yare you supposed to get)? And y is a vowel as well (thy, why. my etc.), so by rights it should be $v=6$..I get the same as the accepted answer, namely 227448.

Comment: It also agrees with Rob Arthan's anwer .It's $24 \times 9477$ in all three answers.

Comment: The correct answer is (1*9*9*9*4*1)*4(rearraging digits)*2(rearraging vowels)

Comment: @DavidSousa So your question was stated wrongly: the code *must* contain exactly one 3 and one a. Not at most one, which is what all answers counted.

Comment: yeah, portuguese is really ambiguous, so it's a bit hard to translate

Answer (score 0):

instead of giving you the answer, I'm going to go through a few things in combinatorics for you ( that may help you understand my questions in the comments etc):

> **Combination**: a way of choosing objects without order mattering, they can be with or without repetition. ( they give different answers depending on scenario).
>
> **Permutation**: an arrangement of objects where order matters, typically they either have fixed points or they don't. Those that don't are known derangements. ( again different answers depending on scenario)
>
> **Partition**: a breakdown of some number of things, where order doesn't matter.
>
> **Composition**: a breakdown of some number of things, where order does matter.